# CIFAR-10 neural net doesn't accept batch

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, tensorflow

I am making a neural network in python using the tensorflow library to classify the CIFAR-10 dataset. The issue is that I cannot find a way of converting the batch so that the train step will accept the feed. This is my code, with sections I have verified to work being replaced with comments describing them:

```
# import statements 
# declare some global variables 
# also declare filepaths 


def read_cifar10(filename_queue): 
    # parse cifar10 file, return as label with uint8image (Cifar10Record) 


def generate_batch(image, label): 
    # generate shuffled batch, given images and labels 


def get_imgs(test = False, fmin = 1, files = 1): 
    # generate the filename(s) and the filename_queue 
    # read the input using read_cifar10 
    # cast it to uint8image and float32 
    # apply distortions 
    # set the shape of the image and label 
    # return the batch, made using generate_batch 


# build placeholders for input and output 
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784]) 
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10]) 

# create a weight variable with a given shape 
# slight amount of variation 
def weight_variable(shape): 
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev = 0.1) 
    return tf.Variable(initial) 

# same but for bias variables 
def bias_variable(shape): 
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape = shape) 
    return tf.Variable(initial)


# convolve it, do some more layers, apply relu, make dropout and readout layers, etc 
# do softmax regression 


# define the loss function, training step, accuracy function 
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_, logits = y_conv)) 
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy) 
guess = tf.argmax(y_conv, 1) 
answer = tf.argmax(y_, 1) 
correct_prediction = tf.equal(guess, answer) 
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)) 

def train_nn(): 
    for i in range(TRAIN_STEPS):
        # this is where the error occurs
        batch = get_imgs(files = 5).eval() 

        # every 100 steps output training accuracy 
        if i % 100 == 0: 
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5}) 
            print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy)) 

        train_step.run(feed_dict = {x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5}) 

def test_nn(): 
    # test it 
    batch = get_imgs(test = True).eval() 
    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})) 

# create session 
with tf.Session() as sess: 
    # initialize global variables 
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 

    # make queue runners 
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator() 
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess = sess, coord = coord) 

    # train it, test it 
    sess.run(train_nn()) 
    sess.run(test_nn()) 

    coord.request_stop() 
    coord.join(threads)
```

Some things I have tried and the results:

- batch = get_imgs(args) gives 'TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.'
- batch = get_imgs(args).eval() gives 'AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'eval''
- batch = sess.run(get_imgs(args)) causes the program to run indefinitely with no output
- printing type(batch) says the batch is a tuple
- printing batch gives a description of a tensor
- printing batch.eval() or type(batch.eval()) gives 'W tensorflow/core/kernels/queue_base.cc:302] _3_input_producer: Skipping cancelled dequeue attempt with queue not closed'

I suspect the issue is either with the batch conversion, the queueing with tf.train.Coordinator(), or the placeholders. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your input queues are not handled correctly. Check the answer to the similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862754/tensorflow-using-an-input-pipeline-csv-as-a-dictionary-for-training/44862968#44862968

Comment: sorry, but i'm not sure i understand how this is different from what i have written. get_imgs() returns a batch made by generate_batch(), which is almost identical to input_pipeline() in that example. the rest of the code in what you wrote seems also to be in my program, some lines word-for-word the same. if you could elaborate that would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't use `feed_dict` when handling queues, check how the queues are handled in the link